# Declare an env var on the fly while adding to PATH

Tags: linux, macos, unix, path

On macOS/Unix/Linux based systems, I know that I could add a path to `PATH` variable in the environment. Something like below works

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/some/tool/
```

**Question:**
Is it possible to declare a variable like `TOOL_ROOT` on the fly? Something like below?

```
export PATH=$PATH:TOOL_ROOT=/path/to/some/tool/
```

I know that above can be achieved by doing following 2 commands but I want to know if if is possible to do it on the fly which adding the path to `PATH`?

```
export TOOL_ROOT=/path/to/some/tool/
export PATH=$PATH:$TOOL_ROOT
```

Comment: What for? Why can't you just write two lines?

Comment: I can. Just asking if that is a possibility for ease of use for some developers using my tool.    Having a setup possible with one liner command is more attractive than 2 lines. I understand many might not agree. I just want to check if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `TOOL_ROOT` isn't already set, you can use the **Assign Default Value** parameter expansion operator.

```
export PATH=$PATH:${TOOL_ROOT:=/path/to/some/tool} TOOL_ROOT
```

You need to specify `TOOL_ROOT` twice: once to set it inline as a shell variable, and then again as an argument to `export` so it gets exported into the environment.

Comment: `export PATH=$PATH:${TOOL_ROOT:=/path/to/some/tool} TOOL_ROOT` would be fine, right? One `export` is fine.

Comment: You're right, I tested it and it works. I've updated the answer.